# How to match everything after a certain word

Tags: python, regex

Hello I am trying to match everything after "http:" and get rid of it.

**Example strings like:**

> New species of fish found at Arkansas http: //t.co/E218nP6DZd
>
> A new fish discovered in Arkansas ( PIGFISH ) http:
>   //t.co/qqoMmHVItg

**Expected result:**

> New species of fish found at Arkansas
>
> A new fish discovered in Arkansas ( PIGFISH )

Thanks :)

Comment: In fact you want whagt is before not after. Easier to keep what is before than remove that is after^^

Comment: Do you mean you just want the substring up to the position of `http:`? That does not require a regular expression.

Comment: You are right, I was overthinking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different way to approach this is to split the string on your target word and return the first part.

```
my_string="New species of fish found at Arkansas http://example"
print(my_string.split("http",1)[0])
#New species of fish found at Arkansas
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `index()` function on your string, which will return the index of the first occurrence of the passed in substring. You can use this to directly slice the part you want:

```
s = "New species of fish found at Arkansas http: //example.com/E218nP6DZd"

s[:s.index('http')]
# 'New species of fish found at Arkansas '
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex that catches what is before the `http`, you may use `search/match` and print the capturing group, or use `findall`, you'll end with the same result

```
values = ["New species of fish found at Arkansas http: //urlshorten",
          "A new fish discovered in Arkansas ( PIGFISH ) http: //urlshorten"]

reg = re.compile("(.*)http")
for value in values:
    txt = reg.findall(value)
    print(txt)

    txt = reg.search(value) # or match
    print(txt.groups())
```

Comment: I just solved this by using 'word.split('http')' which worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

web_string = 'A new fish discovered in Arkansas ( PIGFISH ) http: //website.com/qqoMmHVItg'
match_group = re.match('(.*\( PIGFISH \)) (http.*$)', web_string)

no_http_string = match_group[1]
print(no_http_string)
```

should yield you

```
A new fish discovered in Arkansas ( PIGFISH )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a regex to match with a url.

```
import re
if text.search("http"):
    #code
```

Answer (score 0):

As azro said, easier to capture what is before "http:", and ignore the rest.

Here is a regex I tried using the `re` package that captures `(`...`)` any alphanumeric `\w` or whitespace `\s` at the start of the string, but the text "http" and any number of any type of characters afterwards `.*` are not included in the captured group.

```
([\w\s]*)http.*
```

`[\w\s]*` matches any number of alphanumerics or spaces

`()` includes that in a capture group

`http.*` matches the exact text "http" and any number of any character afterwards.

Here is the python code I ran on your string:

```
s = "New species of fish found at Arkansas https://twitter.com/oliviadodson_/status/445043948969398272/photo/1"
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(  r'([\w\s]*)http.*'  )
>>> m = pat.search( s ); print(m)
>>> m.group(1)
'New species of fish found at Arkansas '
```

This only works on a single line of the text at a time (doesn't include newlines at the end).  You can modify it to fit your exact use case, for example including punctuation in the capture etc.  Use a `for` loop to iterate through the paragraph etc.

Comment: Although you added the tag `regex` to your question, and this answers using regex, I suspect Mark Meyer's answer is actually what you want - maybe you don't care whether you use regex or a built-in python method!